# iOS email with pdf attached 'rejected by server'

Tags: ios, email, pdf, attachment

I have developed an app for a company. The app produces construction site reports which can be exported and emailed. All has been fine but they have just got back to me saying that emails wont send from some devices once the attached pdf gets quite big (>10mb), instead they are saved to outbox and the error 'rejected by server' is shown.

I can't seem to reproduce this error myself and it works on all devices/simulators that I have tried.

The devices that produce the error are all iPad Air 1 with latest iOS installed (9.3).

Any ideas on a solution and reason for this error??

Is there some setting they need to correct with their email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue after much research and failed attempts.

I was placing my images into html from core data where the images were stored as binary data. This data was converted to a base64 string so It could be added to the html, converted to pdf and emailed/printed.

After reading up about images and Core Data I discovered that it is not a recommended idea to store the binary data in the core data and a better solution was to save the image locally to the app and store a reference to the image in core Data i.e the filepath. This fixed the issue, and the reports are now sending without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite safe to assume that it's simply a case of the mail system of certain recipients rejecting attachments of a certain size. I would suggest that manually sending an email with an attachment >10MB to the affected eMail addresses could help to make clear it is not a problem inherent in the app itself.

Alternatively, if possible, it of course would make sense to send smaller PDFs. If the PDFs contain JPEGS it may make sense to experiment with image sizes and compression ratios to try to stay below 10MB.

Comment: Thanks @Markus but it doesn't matter what email you send to be it hotmail, gmail etc

Comment: Could it be a problem with the outgoing mail server instead in these cases?

Comment: I was thinking that as a possibility but not sure what to look for to identify the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You could suggest that people who encounter the problem may want to to try whether they are able to send attachment >10MB from their devices at all.

Comment: It also may be helpful to check whether the attachments to the mails in the outbox open ok on the devices where the failure happens. That should ensure that the mails were not somehow incomplete/damaged.

Comment: Good thinking! I'll see what happens

Comment: I have a similar issue in that no PDFs or images will send from 9.3. The same code on 9.2 will send no problem.